# Adding everything to a 2d arraylist from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

What I am trying to do is I have a text file formatted as follows:

```
1 a w e r s 5 2 d 6
f s d e a 3 6 7 1 32
2 f s 6 d
4 s h y 99 3 s d
7 s x d q s
```

and to have each object in each line be one row in a 2d arraylist; my code is as follows:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        array.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
            String line = scanner.next();
            array.add(line);
            }

            System.out.println(array);
            2dArray.add(array);
        }

        scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

What happens now is that the 2dArray just has the final array repeated like 15 times, and when I print array right before adding it to 2darray it displays exactly what I want to add. Any suggestions on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're inserting the same `array` object over and over again.

Change:

```
array.clear();
```

to:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and remove your current declaration of `array`.

Comment: I did this and now it gives me 9 copies of every array in 2darray instead of just one.

Comment: Remove your inner for loop then, your code works fine with only `while (scanner.hasNextLine())` loop if you want a single copy of each line.

Comment: I want the array to have all the values (the 9 is arbitrarily, I want it to have every object within the given row (with the basic space delimiter) to have its own index.

And once I have this then I want to add every row to 2darray (with each string having its own index)...if that makes sense